# Proper code for $p\to q$ in GAP

Tags: computational-mathematics, gap

I’d like to know if

```
gap> IsBool(not(p) or q)=true;
```

is the only code for checking the trueness of a conditional statement `p->q` or not? I couldn’t find the proper code (if it exists) in GAP.

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code given in the question is not correct. `IsBool` checks the type of its argument, so we have

```
gap> IsBool(true); IsBool(false); IsBool(fail);
true
true
true
```

Therefore, `IsBool(not(p) or q)=true` will be equal to `true` for any `p, q in [true,false]`.

The correct code is just

```
not p or q
```

(also note that there is no need in `()` around `p`):

```
gap> t:=Tuples([true,false],2);
[ [ true, true ], [ true, false ], [ false, true ], [ false, false ] ]
gap> for x in t do Print( x, " ", not x[1] or x[2],"\n");od;
[ true, true ] true
[ true, false ] false
[ false, true ] true
[ false, false ] true
```

Comment: Thanks so much Alex! I see now the right path.